# If $R$ is a right Noetherian ring, then so is $eRe$ for every idempotent $e\in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Recall that a ring $R$ is right Noetherian if for every chain $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq \ldots$ of right ideal of $R$, there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $I_m = I_{m+1}=I_{m+2}=\ldots$.

Assume that $R$ is a right Noetherian ring and $e\in R$ is an idempotent. How can I prove that $eRe$ is a right Noetherian ring as well.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak A$ be a right ideal of $eRe$. We will prove that
$$
(\mathfrak AR) \cap eRe = \mathfrak A.
$$
Indeed, if $\mathfrak A_0 := (\mathfrak AR) \cap eRe$, clearly $\mathfrak A_0 \supseteq \mathfrak A$; and
\begin{align}
\mathfrak A_0 
&= \mathfrak A_0e \qquad (\textrm{since } \mathfrak A_0 \subseteq eRe) \\
&\subseteq \mathfrak A Re \qquad (\mathfrak A_0 \subseteq \mathfrak AR) \\
&= \mathfrak A eRe \qquad (\mathfrak A = \mathfrak Ae) \\
&= \mathfrak A \qquad (\textrm{$\mathfrak A$ is a right ideal of $eRe$})
\end{align}
proving $\mathfrak A_0 = \mathfrak A$.

Conclude that $\mathfrak A \mapsto \mathfrak AR$ is an injective inclusion-preserving map from the right ideals of $eRe$ to those of $R$.

Thus, if $R$ is right Noetherian, then the same holds for $eRe$.

---

#### Reference:

T. Y. Lam. *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*. Second Edition. Theorem 21.11 (p. 311).